# Differential of inverse function to a tubular neighborhood

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, inverse-function, inverse-function-theorem

Suppose $S$ is a (regular) compact differentiable surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so that tubular neighborhoods exist. Consider the diffeomorphism to one of them:

$$F:S\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow N_{\epsilon}(S)$$

$$F(p,t)=p+tN_p$$

where $N$ is the Gauss map, that is invertible. I have to calculate the differential of its inverse, however I think I don't fully understand how am I supposed to express it in general. I know the inverse function $F^{-1}$ takes a point in the neighborhood to a point of the space that has for its two first coordinates the orthogonal projection onto the surface and for the third one the oriented distance from said surface. Every time I try to calculate the inverse I get stuck in some circular reasoning (for example I know how to express the distance in function of the projection and vice versa but I cannot explicitly write both of them). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Differential of the inverse map is just the inverse of the differential of the original map. If you are able to compute $dF$, then it is immediate to compute $dF^{-1}$ just by inverting the differential pointwise.

Comment: @cjackal but the inverse of $dF$ in $p$ is the differential of $F^{-1}$ in $F(p)$ right? So for the differential of $F^{-1}$ at x I need to calculate explicitly $F^{-1}(x)$ or no?

Comment: You can (with a little bit of differential geometry) compute the differential of $F$ at $(p,t)$ and so, inverting (abstractly), you'll have the differential of $F^{-1}$ at $x=F(p,t)$. You won't see it naturally in the Euclidean coordinates on $\Bbb R^3$. You'll see it more naturally in terms of a basis consisting of the principal directions at $p$ and $N_p$.

Comment: @TedShifrin okay but still, once I've inverted the differential how do I write down the point where I calculate it?